# repeat action several times and collect the result

Tags: groovy

I have an `action` which I need to do over an `object` several times and the collect the result of each `action` with that object.

Basically it looks like this

```
def one_action = { obj ->
    def eval_object = process(obj)
    eval_object.processed = true
    return eval_object
}

def multiple_actions = { obj, n, action ->
    def result = []
    n.times {
        result << action(obj)
    }
    return result
}

println multiple_actions(object, 10, one_action)
```

Is there a way to omit declaration of `def result = []` and return the list directly from the closure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `collect` the range, starting from zero:

```
def one_action = { obj ->
    "a $obj"
}

def multiple_actions = { obj, n, action ->
    (0..<n).collect { action obj }
}

assert multiple_actions("b", 3, one_action) == ["a b"] * 3
```